# RAM (Random Access Memory), что имеется в виду под random?

Tags: ram

RAM (Random Access Memory), что имеется в виду под random? Почему оперативка это память СЛУЧАЙНОГО доступа?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC

Comment: произвольного потому что а не случайного.